# Display generates "Field is out of screen boundary" error

Tags: cobol

I get

> Field is out of screen boundary error detected at offset

This is my code:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. LALABS.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.
       SOURCE-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.
       OBJECT-COMPUTER. IBM-PC.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT OUTFILE ASSIGN TO 'NATS'.
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD  OUTFILE
           LABEL RECORD IS OMITTED
           DATA RECORD IS OUTREC.
       01  OUTREC.
           02 FILLER PIC X(80).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  BC  PIC 9 VALUE 0.
       01  TCF   PIC 99 VALUE 0.
       01  RFC  PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  PTF PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  ES  PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  RS  PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  EOFSW PIC 9 VALUE 0.
       01  IR PIC  9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  INPUTZ PIC X VALUE SPACES.
       01  LALAGYANZZ.
           02 LALAGYAN1 PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
           02 LALAGYAN2 PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
           02 LALAGYAN3 PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       01  CTR-STUDENTS.
           02 MAIN-S PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
           02 COMMON-S PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
           02 SJ-S PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
           02 TAG-S PIC 9(5) VALUE 0.
       SCREEN SECTION.
       01  SCRE.
           02 BLANK SCREEN.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-RTN.
           PERFORM INIT-RTN THRU INIT-RTN-END.
           PERFORM PROCESS-RTN UNTIL INPUTZ = 'N' OR 'n'.
           STOP RUN.
       INIT-RTN.
           GO TO INIT-RTN-END.
       INIT-RTN-END.
       PROCESS-RTN.
           DISPLAY SCRE.
           DISPLAY(5, 20) 'POLYTECHNIC UNIVERSITY OF THE PHILIPPINES'.
           DISPLAY(6, 30) 'STA. MESA, MANILA'.
           DISPLAY(9, 30) 'METRO BRANCH CAMPUS'.
           DISPLAY(10, 30) 'POPULATION REPORT'.
           DISPLAY(11, 30) 'FIRST SEMESTER'.
           DISPLAY(12, 30) '2014-2015'.
           PERFORM A.
       A.  DISPLAY(14, 15) 'LOCATION BRANCH CODE:(1/2/3/4)'.
           ACCEPT(14, 55) BC.
           IF BC > 4 OR BC < 1 PERFORM A.
           DISPLAY(15, 15) 'LOCATION NAME:'.
           IF BC = 1 PERFORM MEYN-RTN.
           IF BC = 2 PERFORM COMMON-RTN.
           IF BC = 3 PERFORM SJ-RTN.
           IF BC = 4 PERFORM TAG-RTN.
           DISPLAY(16, 15) 'TOTAL NO. OF COURSE OFFERED:'.
           ACCEPT(16, 55) TCF.
           DISPLAY(17, 15) 'TOTAL NO. OF REGULAR FACULTY:'.
           ACCEPT(17, 55) RFC.
           DISPLAY(18, 15) 'TOTAL NO. OF PART-TIME FACULTY:'.
           ACCEPT(18, 55) PTF .
           DISPLAY(19, 15) 'TOTAL NO. OF ENROLLED STUDENTS:'.
           ACCEPT(19, 55) ES.
           DISPLAY(20, 15) 'TOTAL NO, OF REGULAR STUDENTS:'.
           ACCEPT(20, 55) RS.
           PERFORM IR-RTN.
           DISPLAY(21, 15) 'TOTAL NO: OF IRREGULAR STUDENTS:'.
           DISPLAY(21, 55) IR .
           PERFORM J.
       J.  DISPLAY(22, 15) 'INPUT ANOTHER RECORD(Y/N)?:'.
           ACCEPT(22, 55) INPUTZ.
           IF INPUTZ = 'Y' OR 'N' NEXT SENTENCE ELSE PERFORM J.
           IF INPUTZ = 'Y' PERFORM PROCESS-RTN ELSE PERFORM TOTZ-RTN.
       IR-RTN.
           COMPUTE IR = ES - RS.
       TOTZ-RTN.
           DISPLAY(23, 15) 'LARGEST NO. :'.
           DISPLAY(23, 30) LALAGYAN3.
           DISPLAY(26, 15) 'BRANCH NAME:'.
       MEYN-RTN.
           DISPLAY(15, 50) 'STA. MESA, MAIN'.
           ADD ES TO MAIN-S.
       COMMON-RTN.
           DISPLAY(15, 50) 'COMMONWEALTH'.
           ADD ES TO COMMON-S.
       SJ-RTN.
           DISPLAY(15, 50) 'SAN JUAN'.
           ADD ES TO SJ-S.
       TAG-RTN.
           DISPLAY(15, 50) 'TAGUIG'.
           ADD ES TO TAG-S.
```

Comment: Try removing code until the problem goes away - that is how you create the smallest example of the issue. Very often you will find this is an effective strategy for debugging. You say "I tried everything to make it right" but you don't indicate what you actually did... Makes it hard for anyone to help you. When did the problem first appear? This is COBOL - so probably the original code is old, and worked at some point in the past. What was changed?

Comment: It's tough to help given just a page of code and an error message. Can you explain what you tried to do and maybe zero in on the line that causes that error? Attach the state of the variables at the line of the error and any other log lines.

Comment: Which compiler/OS? Is there any output at all when you run the program?

Comment: Just a guess from the message until further information arrives, try changing the `DISPLAY(26, 15) 'BRANCH NAME:'.` to `DISPLAY(24, 15) 'BRANCH NAME:'.`

Answer (score 1):

```
DISPLAY(23, 15) 'LARGEST NO. :'.
DISPLAY(23, 30) LALAGYAN3.
DISPLAY(26, 15) 'BRANCH NAME:'.
```

Unless you have a 26 line screen (or 27 if it's zero-based), that last `display` may be causing an issue. If you're limited to 25 lines, that's almost certainly the case and you should change the coordinates so that it's placed correctly within the screen bounds.

Comment: Gotta be worth a vote. And a typo close flag. TS/OP hasn't even bothered to visit the site since asking, but can help someone else in the future who doesn't read the error messages :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SCREEN SECTION.
    01  SCRE.
        02 BLANK SCREEN.
```

Your screen section are both group items - No picture clause, wen the compiler compiles this the length will either be 0 or indeterminate depending on the compiler. BTW - what platform / Cobol compiler  are you using?

Comment: The _02 BLANK SCREEN._ is elementary, not group, and is permitted and supported. ISO/IEC 1989:2002(E), Screen description entry, 13.15.2 Syntax rules, 7) For an elementary screen item, the associated screen description entry shall include at least one of the following: a PICTURE clause and a FROM, TO, or USING clause; a PICTURE clause and a VALUE clause with a numeric literal; a VALUE clause specifying an alphanumeric, boolean, or national literal; a **BLANK clause**; a ERASE clause; a BELL clause.

Comment: In other words you are telling me that a black screen will compile into a `1920 or 2000 byte  (24x80, or 25x 80) item under Microfocus.  I am a Mainframe and AS400 Cobol and Assembler programmer since 1984. I've used Microfocus and Relia Cobol in the past  but the target environment is always the IBM mainframes.

Comment: No, all I am saying is that the clause is an elementary data item. However, on PCs with DOS it invokes an interrupt, on Windows it calls a function, with ANSI.SYS it sends an escape sequence defined by ANSI X3.64. On UNIX or Linux it calls ncurses which either clears the screen (local) or sends an escape sequence to a terminal. None of these require that the actual size of the screen be known. The program only needs to know the _dimensions_ of the screen for determining where it can place text. The OP tried to place text on line 26 of a 25-line screen. That was the error.

Comment: In the mainframe - DISPLAY sends the message to the standard output file (SYSOUT -without need to define a SCREEN SECTION) I have always thought that SCREEN Serion implementation of the different compilers are their own - It is not supported by IBM in its different flavours for ZOS, VSE or AS400 nor by Unisys nor can I find it in the ANSI Cobol Standard

Comment: Anyway Nice talking to you, Hope the guy fixes his problem,